# Collision probability with increments

Tags: probability, statistics

Let's build out from a simple example. If we generate $40$-bit uniformly random values (i.e. numbers `[0, 2^40)`), the birthday problem tells us how to calculate certain probabilities. For example, we have about $0.001\%$ chance of at least one collision if we generate $47,000$ such values.

Now let's make the scenario more complex.

Define a set of values as follows (with all generated numbers being uniformly random):

- Generate a $45$-bit number (i.e. `[0, 2^45)`). This is the initial value.
- Repeat the following $224$ times:

  - Generate a nonzero $40$-bit number (i.e. `(0, 2^40)`). Add it to the last seen value to create the next value.
- We thus have $225$ values: the initial one plus all the subsequent increments.

Creating one set, it's easy to see that the collision probability is $0$. Creating multiple sets, the probability is greater than $0$.

It's unclear to me how to calculate for this scenario. What's more, intuitively it seems that the larger initial value makes collisions less likely, but that might be false.

Here are my questions:

1. What is the formula for the probability that at least one value collides with another, given $X$ sets?
2. What are the resulting probabilities for $X=2$, $X=10$, $X=20$, and $X=100$?
3. If we were to repeat the experiment many times, on *average*, we see $1$ collision per how many experiments?

Comment: If zero is a possible 40-bit number then might you get a collision in your first set of 225 values?

Comment: @Henry Good point! No, zero is excluded there.